# Alternatives to Windows Crypto API for C# RSA PKI?

Tags: c#, dll, rsa, public-key-encryption

I'm currently building a secure WhatsApp-like messenger for me and my friends. It encrypts all messages with AES and then uses RSA to encrypt the random AES key, it's very similar to PGP. For the desktop client, I have a nicely working version, but there's one thing that bugs me: at the moment I use the Windows Crypto API for generating key pairs and encrypting/decrypting. To make it short: I don't trust them anymore.

So what I'm looking for is a working and stable library that I can use for all these standard tasks of key creation, de-/encryption, etc. [I found one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/421656/RSA-Library-with-Private-Key-Encryption-in-Csharp) over at the code project, but unfortunately it is quite buggy and unstable. Are there any libraries/frameworks that you can recommend? I really don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) has a c# crypto library. It generally tracks their Java library but not perfectly. It is not well documented. However, I have found the source code to be very readable. What I have done in the past is use the Javadocs for the Java API as a starting point, then looked through the roughly corresponding classes in the c# library.